# What magic items grant you immunity to charm?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, immunities, charmed

In order to find magic items that would counter the Sleep spell, I'm searching for magic items that grant the user immunity to Charm effects. I am asking mostly for NPCs.

In order to best determine a singular answer, the priority is **accessibility**.  That is, what's the most common item that would provide this benefit?

Comment: @NautArch NPCs, mostly.  But I wanted to review official sources first before I started making stuff up.

Comment: @NautArch I considered that, but I'm specifically interested in magic items.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Only 2 magic items specifically grant immunity to the charmed condition

According to [this D&D Beyond search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-requires-attunement=&filter-effect-type=6&filter-effect-subtype=195&filter-has-charges=), only 2 magic items specify that they grant immunity to the charmed condition:

- [Greater Silver Sword](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/greater-silver-sword) (legendary)
- [Staff of the Forgotten One](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-the-forgotten-one) (artifact)

Being a legendary item and an artifact neither of them is usually easily accessible, unfortunately.

Comment: So you're saying there's a chance?